# jquery UI 1.9 Datepicker show empty div when moving between picker

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

jquery ui 1.9 rc with jquery 1.8

i got 2 datepicker on the page when i press on one it worked but when i press the other one it showes a blank small div instead of thr date picker
pressing anywhere on the page will release and the calender will Show

is it a jquery ui bug or I'm doing something wrong?

```
<input type="text" id="datepicker">
<input type="text" id="datepicker2">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../../themes/base/jquery.ui.all.css">
<script src="../../jquery-1.8.0.js"></script>
<script src="../../ui/jquery.ui.core.js"></script>
<script src="../../ui/jquery.ui.widget.js"></script>
<script src="../../ui/jquery.ui.datepicker.js"></script>
<script>
$(function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
    $( "#datepicker2" ).datepicker();
});
</script>
```

Comment: If you don't show any code, it's impossible to answer. Try to reproduce it in a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net), and [report it](http://bugs.jqueryui.com/) if it's indeed a bug.

Comment: it works on 1.8 a workaround so i wont need to downgrade will be nice

Comment: I meant to upgrade, not downgrade. 1.8.1 fixes some issues with the UI, 1.8.2 was released 3 days ago.

Comment: If it is a RC then it is going to have bugs. Report the bug and use a stable version.

Answer (score 1):

Try creating datepicker2 before datepicker. If datepicker2 works and datepicker doesn't you can proceed to debug from there.

Answer (score 1):

Add this css to your page to hide the div ui-datepicker-div :

```css
<!--  datepicker  -->
<style>
    #ui-datepicker-div {
        display: none;
    }
</style>
```